# Erro no R com a função list2env

Tags: r

Tento converter minha lista (que contém 12 dataframes e aprox. 20.000 linhas cada) em dataframes separados:

```
list2env(mylist,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

mas, a seguinte mensagem de erro aparece:

```
names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

O que pode ser e o que fazer?

Comment: Parece que `mylist` não tem o atributo `names`. O que é que `attributes(mylist)` dá? Uma solução poderá ser `names(mylist) <- paste("membro", seq_along(mylist), sep = ".")`.

Comment: Funcionou! Grato pela atenção.

Comment: É que sem nomes como é que o R pode criar objetos no `.GlobalEnv` ou noutro environment qualquer? Passam a ser chamados o quê?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como observado pelo @RuiBarradas, a lista deve ser nomeada que a possa ser transformada em ambiente.

Reproduzindo o erro:

```
mylist <- list(1, 2, "a")
list2env(mylist,envir=.GlobalEnv)
# Error in list2env(mylist, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
#   names(x) deve ser um vetor de caracter de mesmo comprimento que x
```

Aplicando a solução temos

```
names(mylist) <- paste("membro", seq_along(mylist), sep = ".")
ls()
# [1] "mylist"
list2env(mylist,envir=.GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ls()
# [1] "membro.1" "membro.2" "membro.3" "mylist"
```