# Manipulação de colunas-lista

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tenho uma `tibble` denominada `my`, a qual contém a coluna-lista `data`

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*30,1000,100),ncol=6))
cluster<-kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
dataset$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])

my<-dataset%>%
  group_by(kmeans)%>%
  nest()

rm(dataset,cluster)
```

Tenho as seguintes dúvidas referente a manipulação de `colunas-lista`:

- como aplicar a função `nest` e, ao mesmo tempo, manter as variáves de grupo nas `tibble`s? Algo semelhante a função `base::split`.
- como faço para colocar estas colunas-lista no `globalenv()`? Algo semelhante a função `base::list2env`.
- como aplicar um `mutate` e manter os resultados na mesma `tibble`? Considere que cada `tibble` tenha 6 colunas. Com um `mutate_if(is.numeric,sum)`, gostaria que estas `tibble`s tivessem 12 colunas. Já tentei algumas ações, mas elas retornam uma nova coluna-lista, o que não quero.

Todos estes procedimentos eu consigo fazer com as funções correntes do `r`. Mas, tenho interesse em manipular as colunas-lista para permanecer no framework `tidyverse`.

Comment: A primeira já foi respondida no próprio exemplo. Não? Com o `group_by() ` + `nest()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A manipulação de colunas-lista dentro do `tidyverse` ocorre da mesma que este universo se propõe a manipular listas, ou seja, com [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr). A diferença é que esta manipulação ocorre dentro de um `data.frame` e portanto usa as regras do `tidyverse` para manipulá-los - ficando por exemplo dentro de um `mutate()`.

Dada esta consideração de ordem geral, vamos as questões.

### Manter as variáveis no `nest()`

Vejo duas interpretações possíveis para a pergunta. Na primeira delas, em que o resultado esperado está na `tibble` que é resultado de `nest()`, a resposta já está na própria pergunta. Na segunda delas, em que se espera que as variáveis estejam condidas dentro de cada `tibble` aninhada, pode ser resolvido acrescentando a variável nova na `tibble` aninhada com `map()`.

```
my %>% 
  mutate(data2 = map2(data, kmeans, ~mutate(.x, var = .y)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  kmeans data              data2            
  <fct>  <list>            <list>           
1 1      <tibble [14 x 6]> <tibble [14 x 7]>
2 3      <tibble [10 x 6]> <tibble [10 x 7]>
3 2      <tibble [6 x 6]>  <tibble [6 x 7]>
```

### Levar a coluna-lista para o `.GlobalEnv`

Antes de mais nada, se você realmente pretende se manter no *frameword* `tidyverse`, você não deveria fazer isso. Neste caso as informações deveriam ser mantidas na `tibble`. Feita esta ressalva, a operação pode ser feita da mesma forma que colocada [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325607/erro-no-r-com-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-list2env), lembrando que para tal a lista deve ser nomeada. Assim teríamos:

```
ls()
[1] "cluster" "dataset" "my" 
# Adiciona nomes aos elementos da lista
my$data <- set_names(my$data, paste0("tabela", seq_along(my$data)))
list2env(my$data, .GlobalEnv)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ls()
[1] "cluster" "dataset" "my"      "tabela1" "tabela2" "tabela3"
```

## Aplicar mutate

Por fim, para aplicar um `mutate()` numa lista-coluna se dá normalmente, porém para aplicar a operação a data elemento da lista-coluna (que é o desejado neste caso) é preciso incluir um `map()` dentro do `mutate()`.

```
my %>% 
  mutate(soma = map(data, ~mutate_if(.x, is.numeric, sum)),
         final = map2(data, soma, bind_cols)) %>% 
  select(kmeans, final)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  kmeans final             
  <fct>  <list>            
1 1      <tibble [14 x 12]>
2 3      <tibble [10 x 12]>
3 2      <tibble [6 x 12]>
```

Note que bastou incluir o seu código como fórmula dentro do `map()` para que funcionasse. Para produzir o resultado esperado na pergunta eu uni os dois `data.frame`s num único.

Nem toda operação com coluna-lista precisa resultar em outra coluna lista. Para tal, basta usar alguma das variações do `map_*()`.

```
my %>% 
  mutate(tamanho = map_dbl(data, nrow))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  kmeans data              tamanho
  <fct>  <list>              <dbl>
1 1      <tibble [14 x 6]>      14
2 3      <tibble [10 x 6]>      10
3 2      <tibble [6 x 6]>        6
```